# Display two files side by side

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, gnu-coreutils

How can 2 unsorted text files of different lengths be display side by side *(in columns)* in a `shell`

Given `one.txt` and `two.txt`:

```
$ cat one.txt
apple
pear
longer line than the last two
last line

$ cat two.txt
The quick brown fox..
foo
bar 
linux

skipped a line
```

Display:

```
apple                               The quick brown fox..
pear                                foo
longer line than the last two       bar 
last line                           linux

                                    skipped a line
```

`paste one.txt two.txt` almost does the trick but doesn't align the columns nicely as it just prints one tab between column 1 and 2. *I know how to this with emacs and vim but want the output displayed to stdout for piping ect.*

The solution I came up with uses `sdiff` and then pipes to sed to remove the output `sdiff` adds.

`sdiff one.txt two.txt | sed -r 's/[<>|]//;s/(\t){3}//'`

I could create a function and stick it in my `.bashrc` but surely a command for this exists already (or a *cleaner* solution potentially)?

Comment: Not in a shell, but worth mentioning: use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/)!

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can use `pr` to do this, using the `-m` flag to merge the files, one per column, and `-t` to omit headers, eg.

```
pr -m -t one.txt two.txt
```

outputs:

```
apple                               The quick brown fox..
pear                                foo
longer line than the last two       bar
last line                           linux

                                    skipped a line
```

#### See Also:

- **[Print command result side by side](https://askubuntu.com/a/918859/12607)**
- **[Combine text files column-wise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise/16465)**

Comment: Perfect! Knew something would exist, never heard of `pr` before. I tried with 3 files and the output was truncated but the `-w` option solved that. Nice answer.

Comment: @sudo_o: Happy to help, coreutils is full of gems

Comment: Is there a way for pr to auto-detect screen width?

Comment: @Matt: You could use `$COLUMNS`, which should be provided by the shell.

Comment: When used to print two files side by side, `pr` cuts the end of long lines. Is there a way to make it wrap the lines?

Comment: @molnarg: One method is to first fold each input file to half the page width, less any column-separator width. EG, in `bash`: `pr -t -m -w $PAGE_WIDTH <(fold -w $HALF_PAGE_WIDTH one.txt) <(fold -w $HALF_PAGE_WIDTH two.txt)`. This could be solved elegantly in user-created script.

Comment: Is there a way to show 1 line from first file and 10 lines from the second file? Its machine translation outputs that I want to view side by side.

Comment: `pr -mtJ ...` to use all available width.

Comment: can I apply this for output of two processes instead of a file?

Comment: Thanks for the hints here. I've used it in a bash script: pr -m -t -w$((2 * $(cat $1 $2|wc -L))) $1 $2

Answer (score 47):

To expand a bit on [@Hasturkun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20270/hasturkun)'s answer: by default `pr` uses only 72 columns for its output, but it's relatively easy to make it use all available columns of your terminal window:

```
pr -w $COLUMNS -m -t one.txt two.txt
```

Most shells will store *(and update)* your terminal's screenwidth in the `$COLUMNS` shell variable, so we're just passing that value on to `pr` to use for its output's width setting.

This also answers [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193244/matt)'s question:

> Is there a way for pr to auto-detect screen width?

So, no: `pr` itself can't detect the screenwidth, but we're helping it out a bit by passing in the terminal's width via its `-w` option.

Note that `$COLUMNS` is a shell variable, not an environment variable, so it isn't exported to child processes, and hence the above approach will likely not work in scripts, only in interactive TTYs... see [LINES and COLUMNS environmental variables lost in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/) for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 9):

If you know the input files have no tabs, then using `expand` simplifies [@oyss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249545/oyss)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13343584/4263262):

```
paste one.txt two.txt | expand --tabs=50
```

If there could be tabs in the input files, you can always expand first:

```
paste <(expand one.txt) <(expand two.txt) | expand --tabs=50
```

Answer (score 7):

```
paste one.txt two.txt | awk -F'\t' '{
    if (length($1)>max1) {max1=length($1)};
    col1[NR] = $1; col2[NR] = $2 }
    END {for (i = 1; i<=NR; i++) {printf ("%-*s     %s\n", max1, col1[i], col2[i])}
}'
```

Using `*` in a format specification allows you to supply the field length dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know the actual difference between two files side by side, use `diff -y`:

```
diff -y file1.cf file2.cf
```

You can also set an output width using the `-W, --width=NUM` option:

```
diff -y -W 150 file1.cf file2.cf
```

and to make `diff`'s column output fit your current terminal window:

```
diff -y -W $COLUMNS file1.cf file2.cf
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `sed` way:

```
f1width=$(wc -L <one.txt)
f1blank="$(printf "%${f1width}s" "")"
paste one.txt two.txt |
    sed "
        s/^\(.*\)\t/\1$f1blank\t/;
        s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 /;
    "
```

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use `printf -v`:

```
f1width=$(wc -L <one.txt)
printf -v f1blank "%${f1width}s"
paste one.txt two.txt |
    sed "s/^\(.*\)\t/\1$f1blank\t/;
         s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 /;"
```

<sub>(Of course @Hasturkun 's solution `pr` is the **most accurate**!)</sub>:

#### Advantage of `sed` over `pr`

You can finely choose separation width and or separators:

```
f1width=$(wc -L <one.txt)
(( f1width += 4 ))         # Adding 4 spaces
printf -v f1blank "%${f1width}s"
paste one.txt two.txt |
    sed "s/^\(.*\)\t/\1$f1blank\t/;
         s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 /;"
```

Or, for sample, to mark lines containing `line`:

```
f1width=$(wc -L <one.txt)
printf -v f1blank "%${f1width}s"
paste one.txt two.txt |
    sed "s/^\(.*\)\t/\1$f1blank\t/;
  /line/{s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 |ln| /;ba};
         s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 |  | /;:a"
```

will render:

```
apple                         |  | The quick brown fox..
pear                          |  | foo
longer line than the last two |ln| bar 
last line                     |ln| linux
                              |  | 
                              |ln| skipped a line
```

Comment: ```bash
f1width=$(wc -L <one.txt)
printf -v f1blank "%${f1width}s"
paste one.txt two.txt |
    sed "s/^\(.*\)\t/\1$f1blank\t/;
  /line/{s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 |ln| /;ba};
         s/^\(.\{$f1width\}\) *\t/\1 |  | /;:a"
```

Nice solution!! really helpful in other contexts

Answer (score 2):

remove dynamically field length counting from Barmar's answer will make it a much shorter command....but you still need at least one script to finish the work which could not be avoided no matter what method you choose.

```
paste one.txt two.txt |awk -F'\t' '{printf("%-50s %s\n",$1,$2)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Find below a python based solution.

```
import sys

# Specify the number of spaces between the columns
S = 4

# Read the first file
l0 = open( sys.argv[1] ).read().split('\n')

# Read the second file
l1 = open( sys.argv[2] ).read().split('\n')

# Find the length of the longest line of the first file
n = len(max(l0, key=len))

# Print the lines
for i in  xrange( max( len(l0), len(l1) ) ):

    try:
        print l0[i] + ' '*( n - len(l0[i]) + S) + l1[i]
    except:
        try:
            print ' ' + ' '*( n - 1 + S) + l1[i]
        except:
            print l0[i]
```

**Example**

```
apple                            The quick brown fox..
pear                             foo
longer line than the last two    bar 
last line                        linux

                                 skipped a line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -y <file1> <file2>


[root /]# cat /one.txt
```

```
apple
pear
longer line than the last two
last line
```

```
[root /]# cat /two.txt
```

```
The quick brown fox..
foo
bar
linux
```

```
[root@RHEL6-64 /]# diff -y one.txt two.txt
```

```
apple                                                         | The quick brown fox..
pear                                                          | foo
longer line than the last two                                 | bar
last line                                                     | linux
```

Comment: `sdiff` is `diff -y` which I discuss in the question.

Comment: Yes right... it was mentioned to show another command/flag setting of doing it.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the questions `diff` adds characters between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution which is able to paste N files side by side with a changeable separator reading the files only once.  Automatically adjusting to the width of the lines.  The easiest way I found was to do it with a an `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# vim: ft=awk
# This is CC0

BEGIN   { if (SEP==0 && SEP=="") SEP=" ! " }
FNR==1  { W[FILENO++]=MAX+length(SEP); MAX=0 }
        { C[FILENO,FNR] = $0;
          if (length($0)>MAX) MAX=length($0);
          if (FNR>TOT) TOT=FNR;
        }
END     { for (x=0; ++x<=TOT; )
            {
              for (y=0; ++y<=FILENO; )
                {
                  s = C[y,x];
                  i = W[y] - length(s);
                  printf("%s", s);
                  if (i>0)
                    printf("%*s", i, SEP);
                }
              printf("\n");
        }   }
```

Save this to a file called `side-by-side`, make it executable and put it in your `$PATH`.

Then you can call it (FYI `<(..)` is a `bash`ism) for example like this:

```
side-by-side <(df -h) <(df -hi)
```

> Note that I found no easy way to print the free inodes along with the free file space, so the easiest way was to put it side-by-side.

It works with any number of files.  If you give no file (or `-`), `stdin` is read instead (so it works like a buffered `/bin/cat`).  Note that this is just what `awk` does.

How it works:

- The 1st rule initializes the SEP variable.  You can change it with something like `side-by-side -v SEP=" !===! " FILES..` (as you can add `awk` options as usual).

  - `SEP==0 && SEP==""` only is true if `SEP` is uninitialized.
- The 2nd rule counts the files and remembers the width of the previous file
- The 3rd rule remembers the lines and calculates the maximum width of each file and the maximum length of the files
- The last rule then outputs everything side by side with SEP in between of the files

  - There is a trick.  Rule 2 is not executed after the last file.  Hence `W[FILENO]` stays 0 such that `i` stays below 1, such that the `SEP` is not output after the last file's lines.

The script certainly can be optimized a bit, but then probably becomes less readable.

Notes:

- If you use option `-vSEP=''` things are glued together

  - The `''` is for illustration purpose and can be left away.
- If you replace `/usr/bin/awk` with `/usr/bin/gawk` you also get the `gawk` features like `/dev/tcp/` sockets for files.